In react how to build urls as "http://localhost:3000/app?path=user.home"
how do I provide ?path=some_path
and every time I just want to change the some_path to access home,about,details etc
and what is effective and reliable way to get this functionality in React?
I'm a bit familiar with Routers, but the functionality is little new to me
Also I'm using the React-router-dom v6

Please add more details like are you using react-router-dom or something else for navigation?

@Beast80K
I'm using the react-router-dom,
but how do I achieve the above functionality using it?

App.js
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PageLayout } from './PageLayout';

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<div>Root</div>}/>
                <Route path="/app" element={<PageLayout/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;

PageLayout.js
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';

export const PageLayout = () => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const url = query.get('path')

    const RenderOutlet = () => {
        if (!url) {
            return <Home />;
        }
        switch (url) {
            case 'home': return <Home/>;
            case 'about': return <About/>;
            default: return <div>404! Page Not Found!</div>;
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <RenderOutlet/>
        </div>
    );
};

Note: Search parameters is not good practice of routing for base routes. It should be used for parametric routings like search, filter, tokens, etc.
